# Window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame doesnt exist in React TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The problem what I have is that React TS throws an error for my     `window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame` and `window.mozRequestAnimationFrame` thinking that I mean `'requestAnimationFrame'` instead. Should I replace it with something else?

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

export interface Props {
canvas: HTMLElement;
particles: number;
}

function App(props: Props) {

props.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = props.canvas.getContext("2d");

props.particles = [];

props.canvas.onmousedown = function (e: any) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 36 * 2; i++) {
    props.particles.push({
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY,
      angle: i * 5,
      size: 5 + Math.random() * 3,
      life: 200 + Math.random() * 50,
    });
  }
};

props.canvas.onmouseup = function () {
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
};

var delta = 0;
var last = Date.now();

function animate() {
  delta = Date.now() - last;
  last = Date.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < props.particles.length; i++) {
    var p = props.particles[i];
    p.x += Math.cos(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
    p.y += Math.sin(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
    p.life -= delta;
    p.size -= delta / 50;

    if (p.size <= 0) {
      p.life = 0;
    }

    if (p.life <= 0) {
      props.particles.splice(i--, 1);
      continue;
    }
  }
}

function render() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
  for (var i = 0; i < props.particles.length; i++) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
      continue;
    }
    var p = props.particles[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
  return (
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function (callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
  );
})();

(function animloop() {
  requestAnimFrame(animloop);
  animate();
  render();
})();
  return <canvas id="canvas" width="100vw" height="100vh"></canvas>;
}

export default App;
```

**Edit:**
Edited to only ask one question instead of many in this thread.

Comment: This seems like a few questions in one. I will answer about the error you are getting in Typescript. But if you need help with other parts of this you make a new _specific_ question that addresses one problem at a time. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, how is this "typescript" or "bezier"? And since you're asking about doing things on the canvas, which is distinctly not managed by react because it's not related to the DOM, how is this "reactjs"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame()` has [been available in all major browsers for years](https://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe) by now. According to that link, it looks like the last browser releases that included the prefixed version were release 2012-2014.

So it's probably safe to use `requestAnimationFrame` directly, and then you can remove the polyfill altogether.